# Show that $\int _X f \:\:d\mu$ is NOT dependent on the representation of the simple function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space. I need to show that $\int _X f \:\:d\mu$ is NOT dependent on the representation of the simple function $f$. That means: For $M, N \in \Bbb N ; \: \: \alpha_1 , \dots , \alpha _N \lt 0; \: \:\beta_1, \dots \beta _ M \lt 0 ;\: \: A_1 , \dots , A_N \in \mathcal A$ and $B_1 , \dots , B_M \in \mathcal A$ are chosen so that: $$f=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha _i \chi_{A_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{M} \beta _i \chi_{B_i} $$ it is true that: $$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha _i \mu (A_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{M} \beta _i \mu (B_i) $$

It's obvious that this should be the case, but how do i write it down in a formal prove?

Any tipps or ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider the intersections $A_i\cap B_j$. Also, the $A_i$ should be disjoint as well as the $B_j$.

Comment: First construct a representation $$f = \sum_{k = 1}^K \gamma_k\chi_{C_k}$$  where the $C_k$ are disjoint. Look at $\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$ for $I \subseteq \{1,2,\dotsc,N\}$ to get that. Show that $\sum \alpha_i\mu(A_i) = \sum_{\gamma_k}\mu(C_k)$.